# Unable to use JitPack repository - Android

Tags: android, android-library, jitpack

All day I'm trying to add my Android library to Github with JitPack.
I did everything described on: https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/, with no success.

The problem is, when i try to build project, Android Studio give me message:

```
Error:(47, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.linean:btleuart:v1.0.0
```

Here is my repo: https://github.com/linean/btleuart

If anyone have any idea what should I check please tell me.

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Show your gradle file, please

Comment: If you mean my app gradle thats not a problem for sure, because it work with sample JitPack library :(
https://github.com/jitpack/android-example

Comment: I think you want `btleuart:1.0.0`. Remove the `v`

Comment: Actually, the build failed. Check the logs. I'm not sure just "any project" can just be downloaded by JitPack. https://jitpack.io/com/github/linean/btleuart/v1.0.0/build.log

Comment: It still don't work. Version is v1.0.0 for sure https://github.com/linean/btleuart/releases

Comment: Thanks, how did you get this log :) ? I didn't know about that

Comment: Went to the root page. https://jitpack.io/ copied your Github link, click logs. On that note, I see your logs say Gradle 2.14.1, but the instructions on the site say "Gradle 3.0 or later"

Comment: Yes, but that instruction for JitPack 1.5, and below is link to older version. It says that JitPack 1.4.1 works with gradle 2.14+, so I use 1.4.1.

Comment: Okay, I see. Have you ran the `./gradlew install` command yourself in the terminal? The logs do say "Task 'install' not found in root project", so that would indicate to me that it shouldn't work locally either

Comment: Unfortunately i have, and the result is: BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 3):

The release **"v1.0.0" does not exist**. The **release name is "1.0.0"**. So, in your app or library gradle file, replace

```
compile 'com.github.linean:btleuart:v1.0.0'
```

by

```
compile 'com.github.linean:btleuart:1.0.0'
```

In addition, make sure that you have included JitPack repo in your root gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

You can read some examples describing [how to use JitPack to include libraries in your projects](https://solidgeargroup.com/jitpack-public-repositories-android)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution !

1. Clean project
2. use /.gradlew build
3. use /.gradlew install
4. Compille project
5. Git - and now its working

Thanks cricket_007 for info about JitPack build log :)

Answer (score 0):

main build.gradle file should have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

you can check a working example here: https://github.com/matoelorriaga/pokemon-mvp/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: I added it, but still result it's the same. I understand that: main build.gradle in app which loading library should have maven url, it's not correct ?

And JitPack example don't have it in their library